# How to upload picture and store to database in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to upload picture and store to database in Laravel 5.

My current code is:

**Form:**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ url('products/new) }}">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="image">Image</label>
        <input type="file" id="image">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|max:100|unique:products',
    ]);

    $input = $request->all();
    Product::create($input);

    return redirect('products');
}
```

The function `$request->hasFile('image'))` returns `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hasFile('image')` returns `false` because there is not an input with name 'image', only the id is 'image'

You should give it a `name` property, since that's the way the inputs are sent through http.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
<input type="file" id="image">
```

use this

```
<input name="image" type="file" id="image">
```

and in your validator use this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'image' => 'required|max:100|unique:products',
]);
```